# Android autocomplete null pointer

Tags: android, autocomplete, nullpointerexception

i'm having some trouble with the autocomplete textview in android. I populate the array with contact names but still it gives me this errors. What can be wrong?

Here is the code:

```
           @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        contactArr = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
        names=new ArrayList<String>();
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        test();
        Log.v("test", names.get(3));
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.list_item, names);
//      autoComplete.setThreshold(2);
        autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
}
```

Here is how names arraylist is populated:

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String name = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            names.add(name); //populated here
```

And finally the errors from logcat:

```
04-30 19:26:15.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25176): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 19:26:15.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25176): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.contact/com.contact.ContactInfoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-30 19:26:15.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25176):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
04-30 19:26:15.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25176):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
04-30 19:26:15.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25176):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-30 19:26:15.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25176):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
04-30 19:26:15.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25176):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-30 19:26:15.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25176):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-30 19:26:15.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25176):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
04-30 19:26:15.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25176):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 19:26:15.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25176):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-30 19:26:15.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25176):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
04-30 19:26:15.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25176):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
04-30 19:26:15.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25176):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-30 19:26:15.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25176): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-30 19:26:15.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25176):    at com.contact.ContactInfoActivity.onCreate(ContactInfoActivity.java:41)
04-30 19:26:15.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25176):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-30 19:26:15.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25176):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
04-30 19:26:15.389: E/AndroidRuntime(25176):    ... 11 more
```

When i remove this line autoComplete.setThreshold(2);
the new error in log cat is->

```
04-30 19:37:10.319: E/AndroidRuntime(25564):    at com.contact.ContactInfoActivity.onCreate(ContactInfoActivity.java:42)
```

Comment: It says line 41 of your activity.  Which line is line 41?

Comment: @AlexanderLucas this is line 41 autoComplete.setThreshold(2);

Comment: Please include your entire onCreate() method.

Comment: @Sam onCreate method included

Comment: Great, check my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `autoComplete.setThreshold(2);` causes a null pointer, then it sounds like you haven't defined `autoComplete.`

You need to set it up similar to this:

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompletetextView) findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
```

Comment: YES somehow I've forgot to setup the autocompletetextview, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The variable autoComplete is null.  setThreshhold and setAdapter are throwing NPE exceptions because you're trying to access an object that hasn't been instantiated.

To test this, just check:

```
if(autoComplete == null) {
    Log.e("MyApp", "autoComplete is null");
}
```